# Regex to check for leading 0 or blank space

Tags: regex, leading-zero

I'm parsing a integar, searching for either a white space or a leading 0. How do I use a regular expression using an inequality to compare to either of these?

Comment: You would make an attempt at it.  When it doesn't work, you would try a couple more things.  Then when that doesn't work, you would post your question on SO with the attempts you made, then the community would be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

A pattern for this is pretty simple. I used `^[0\s]+`

You just replace it with `""` as you can see in [this example.](https://regex101.com/r/EDKyKZ/9)

It matches a pattern that starts with 1 or more 0's *or* one or more whitespace characters.